# Why does this loop not print the same value continuously?

Tags: c, file, while-loop, stdio

I am trying to understand some C code I've stumbled across.  For the record, the code does exactly what it's supposed to except for the print line I added.  It takes all of the contents from the `inputFile.txt`, and replaces the J's with X's, and writes it to the `outputFile.txt`.

```
int main(void) {
    int fd_to_read = open("inputFile.txt", O_RDONLY);
    int fd_to_write = open("outputFile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);

    char c;
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = read(fd_to_read, &c, sizeof(c))) > 0) {
        if (c == 'J') {
            c = 'X';
        }
        write(fd_to_write, &c, sizeof(c));
        //I added this and it doesn't work.
        printf(&c);
    }
    close(fd_to_read);
}
```

When I first saw this, I expected the while loop to print the first character from the file over and over again.  I understand that the `read()` function will be executed until it is `>0`, but I assumed that in order for it to change position in the file the memory address pointed to by `c` would have to increment by something, possibly the `sizeof(c)`, but nothing appears to increment and it just moves on to the next letter in the file.  My next assumption is that `read()` handles that on it's own, but when I went to print the contents of `&c` I got close to what I expected, which was a ton of garbage, since it was just printing random things from memory essentially.

So, two questions really.

1. How is the `&c` that is written to the `outputFile.txt` write to that correctly without incrementing the address of `c`?
2. How would I just print the individual characters from the file without all the garbage since `print(&c)` added all the garbage after each char?

Comment: 1. it doesn't need to be incremented. byte is written into `c` which is a buffer. buffer content is then written into `fd_to_write` 2. `printf("%c",c);`

Comment: In each loop pass, you read a single character, replace it if it is a 'J', and then write it to an output file. The same variable 'c' is always used. And as @mangusta already mentioned, you should correct your printf statement to output this variable in stdout. Otherwise you are using the single char variable 'c' as a format string, that is not terminated with a null-byte, therefore resulting in undefined behaviour. In your case this results in seeing garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok two things.

(1) `char c` does not need to be incremented because it is serving like the *output* to the `read` fn.

(2) the `read` and `write` fn's automatically increment their respective file descriptors.

The file descriptors (`fd_to_read`, `fd_to_write`) represent a location in the file, not `char c`.

Read about it in the man pages:
https://linux.die.net/man/3/read
https://linux.die.net/man/3/write

Answer (score 0):

`char c; ... printf(&c);` is UB, yet I suspect OP knows that.

The first arg to `printf()` must be a pointer to a *string*.  `&c` is not a pointer to a *string*.

OP is hoping for favorable UB.  Good luck.